# Text based UML Diagram Generators

Tags: svg, uml, ascii, generator, diagram

Which generator tools do you know that are able to generate UML (and perhaps other) diagrams out of text (simple ASCII) based input?

I know about http://plantuml-depend.sourceforge.net/screenshot/screenshot.html

I'm looking for something like

- http://yuml.me/
- https://www.websequencediagrams.com/#

Requirements:

- Generator shouldn't have too many dependencies
- CLI based - specify input and output file
- Output names should be predictable or specifiable
- Possible output formats: SVG, PNG, JPEG, PDF
- Generator should be free to use, or available for purchase (no subscription)
- Ideally diagram layouting can be influenced in case default layout isn't pleasant
- Clean visual diagrams - pleasant to view and read
- Actively maintained software

Alternatively to a CLI Tool reading ASCII input I'd also be interested in UML Libraries.

Thanks so far
Claude

Comment: The [ADia](https://github.com/pylover/adia) is exactly developing for this purpose.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know I keep the most extensive list of textual UML tools here: http://modeling-languages.com/uml-tools/#textual

Hope you'll find at least one that you like

Comment: thank you! there are indeed a few interesting tools that might fit my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

StarUml - http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/ is open source editor that stores result in XML file. Export to pictures is supported

Comment: thanks, but actually am looking for tools that use text input.

Comment: While I really enjoy using StarUML, especially 2.0, keep in mind that it strictly follows the UML 2.0 specification to-the-letter.  There is zero room to go outside the spec.  That can be a bonus or a negative, depending on your needs.